# Adjust breakable longtable inside a tcolorbox

Tags: margins, longtable, tcolorbox

I need a `tcolorbox` with a `longtable` inside but I can't adjust the *right* margin.

Actually, I want a rounded title and a frame with a breakable table which could be placed at any place of the page.

Note: I'm already tried every `0pt` option that I've found but it doesn't seem enough ...

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %colr
\usepackage[raster,skins]{tcolorbox} %textbox
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}

\begin{document}%\layout

\vspace*{550px}


\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTright}{0pt}

\tcbset{
    breakable,  enhanced,   
    left*=0pt,right*=0pt,
    top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
    toptitle=0mm, bottomtitle=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,
    boxrule=2pt, % NO EFFECT
}

\begin{tcolorbox}\textsl{•}[title=\strut\textsc{This is a colorbox}]
\begin{longtable}[]{l|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|l}

    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor{black}\color{white} \textbf{\textsc{This is the table header}} } \\ \hline
    1 & text description & second text & date \\ \hline
    2 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    3 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    4 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    5 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    6 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    7 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    8 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    9 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    11 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    12 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    13 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    14 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    15 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

What is the problem with this code? Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tabular is just not wide enough, since the widths of all columns added together don't add up to `\textwidth`.

To simplify the calculation of the correct widths, you could make use of the `X` column type provided by the `xltabular` package, that will stretch to the remaining space. If you wish to use a `longtable`, you should use the package `xltabular` that combines the `longtable` and the `tabularx` packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %colr
\usepackage[raster,skins]{tcolorbox} %textbox
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}

\begin{document}%\layout

\vspace*{550px}

\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTright}{0pt}

\tcbset{
    breakable, enhanced,   
    left*=0pt, right*=0pt,
    top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
    toptitle=0mm, bottomtitle=0mm,
    boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt,
    boxrule=2pt, % NO EFFECT
}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\strut\textsc{This is a colorbox}]
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{l|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|X}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\cellcolor{black}\color{white} \textbf{\textsc{This is the table header}} } \\ \hline
    1 & text description & second text & date \\ \hline
    2 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    3 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    4 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    5 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    6 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    7 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    8 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    9 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    11 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    12 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    13 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    14 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline
    15 & text description &  second text & date \\ \hline 
\end{xltabular}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]